# Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression on jQuery Form Validator plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have problem on loading security module from [jQuery Form Validator plugin](http://www.formvalidator.net):

```
$.validate({
    modules : 'security'
});
```

I'm using webpack and Laravel-mix for boundeling my files and I got this error:

Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression.

Every thing is fine and even the validations is working but this warning might break some other files to be bundled.

I found that this is problem with [`loadModules` function](https://github.com/victorjonsson/jQuery-Form-Validator/issues/602#issuecomment-353351505).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how you can fix it:
Instead of loading the whole `security.js` or other modules you should grape your validation from that module instead of loading it all and then add it to your main js file. Here I need confirmation from security.js:

```
import './form-validation';
  $.formUtils.addValidator({
name: 'confirmation',
validatorFunction: function (value, $el, config, language, $form) {
  var password,
    passwordInputName = $el.valAttr('confirm') ||
      ($el.attr('name') + '_confirmation'),
    $passwordInput = $form.find('[name="' + passwordInputName + '"]');
  if (!$passwordInput.length) {
    $.formUtils.warn('Password confirmation validator: could not find an input ' +
      'with name "' + passwordInputName + '"', true);
    return false;
  }

  password = $passwordInput.val();
  if (config.validateOnBlur && !$passwordInput[0].hasValidationCallback) {
    $passwordInput[0].hasValidationCallback = true;
    var keyUpCallback = function () {
      $el.validate();
    };
    $passwordInput.on('keyup', keyUpCallback);
    $form.one('formValidationSetup', function () {
      $passwordInput[0].hasValidationCallback = false;
      $passwordInput.off('keyup', keyUpCallback);
    });
  }

  return value === password;
},
errorMessage: '',
errorMessageKey: 'notConfirmed'
});


$.validate({
 form: '#signup-header',
});
```